# How to mock jsonwebtoken + jwsks-rsa for custom lambda Authroizer

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, jestjs, auth0

I am using lambda custom authoriser in front of api endpoint.
so whenever a request comes on that endpoint api gateway calls authoriser  to validate jwt token and based on validation it generates a policy.

Also jwt tokens are generated by auth0 api, i know there is a library https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-jwks which mocks auth0 jwt token but it a http request to endpoint which is not possible in my case

the code is pretty self explanatory howver i stuck with mocking jsonwebtoken and jwks-rsa library? what could be the ideal way to test such kind of function?

my authorizer.js

```
require('dotenv').config();

const jwks = require('jwks-rsa');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const createPolicyDocument = (effect) => {
  const policy = {
    Version: '2012-10-17',
    Statement: [
      {
        Effect: effect,
        Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
        Resource:
          'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      },
    ],
  };

  return policy;
};

// Extract the Bearer token from the event sent by lambda and return it to the authorizer

const extractToken = (event) => {
  const tokenWithBearer = event.authorizationToken;

  if (!tokenWithBearer) {
    throw new Error(' "event.authorization" paramters is missing');
  }

  const bearer = tokenWithBearer.split(' ');

  if (!bearer) {
    throw new Error('Invalid token');
  }

  return bearer[1];
};

const jwtVerifyOptions = {
  audience: process.env.AUDIENCE,
  issuer: process.env.TOKEN_ISSUER,
};

const client = jwks({
  cache: true,
  rateLimit: true,
  jwksRequestsPerMinute: 10,
  jwksUri: process.env.JWKS_URI,
});

function verifyToken(token) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const tempDecodedToken = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });
    console.log(token);
    console.log(tempDecodedToken);
    const { kid } = tempDecodedToken.header;
    client.getSigningKey(kid, (err, key) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('signinin key get error', err);
        reject('Deny');
      }
      const signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
      console.log(signingKey);
      jwt.verify(token, signingKey, jwtVerifyOptions, (error, decoded) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('jwt verify error', error);
          reject('Deny');
        }
        console.log(decoded);
        resolve({ response: 'Allow', decoded });
      });
    });
  });
}

module.exports.auth = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    const token = extractToken(event);
    const tokenResponse = await verifyToken(token);
    console.log(tokenResponse);

    if (tokenResponse.response === 'Allow') {
      return {
        principalId: tokenResponse.decoded.sub,
        policyDocument: createPolicyDocument('Allow'),
        context: { scope: tokenResponse.decoded.scope },
      };
    }
    return {
      policyDocument: createPolicyDocument('Deny'),
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      policyDocument: createPolicyDocument('Deny'),
    };
  }
};
```